# Xcode; Getting "Instance member 'string' cannot be used on type 'VC'" when trying to store in struct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, nsuserdefaults

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

I want to store data with `NSUserDefaults`.

But I'm getting `Instance member 'firstString' cannot be used on type 'VC'` and `Instance member 'secondString' cannot be used on type 'VC'` for the struct.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class Register: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstString: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondString: UITextField!

    struct storeLogin {
        static let storeFirstString = (firstString.text)
        static let storeSecondString = (secondString.text)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can't use a property in class scope.

Comment: So, what to do? What does it mean? (Sorry, I'm new at programming.)

Comment: I updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I'm using the following code to store TextFields content in NSUserDefaults:

```
let loginData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

loginData.setValue(self.username.text, forKey: "Username")
loginData.setValue(self.password.text, forKey: "Password")
```

I'm using this code to get the data from NSUserDefaults:

```
let retrieveData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let username = retrieveData.stringForKey("Username"){
print(username)
}
if let password = retrieveData.stringForKey("Password"){
print(password)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a body of a function to set a properties value to the other property in your case (saving a `UITextFields` value to a `let`) and the reason why is because - properties start initialising themselves only when a class is run or executed that too in a random order, which means by the time your **struct** properties are initialised ,there might be a probable scenario in which struct get initialised before than your textfield's are even initialised. so you need to put this piece of code where you initialise one property to save those to a different property.

```
struct storeData {
    let saveFirstString : String?
    let saveSecondString : String?
  }
```

And every time you want to store to your data just append to an array of type `storeData`

```
class myclass: ...{

    struct storeData {
    let saveFirstString : String?
    let saveSecondString : String?
  } 

    var myData = [stroeData]()//Define this variable globally

     //Check if your textfield is updated or whenevea you want to store to NSUserDefaults 


     func loginBtn(){

       myData.append(storeData.init(saveFirstString: "dasda", saveSecondString: "dasda")
       //Call this line of code whenever you want to store the values in your NSUserDefaults 
      }
 }
```

Comment: Aceep and upvote this answer if it resolves your issue.:)

Comment: I'm not able to use your second code. Doesn't work. I'm getting only errors. Where to add the second code?

Comment: To tell you where to put that code give me your entire code of the class , also tell me when you want to store those values to that struct properties....Give me some basic info....!